# Composite post sleeves deteriorating

Tags: decking, composite

I have several 4x4 deck railing posts wrapped in composite sleeves.  Some of the sleeves are rotting or deteriorating and I’m looking for solutions.  I have considered replacing them but the colors of any new sleeve will not match the existing deck and they will be difficult to install.  I am thinking that pulling off the rotted sleeves and trying to stain the posts with a color matched stain might be the best option.  Has anyone had experience with this and what did you do?

[image: deteriorating composite sleeve]

Comment: Remove all the sleeves (damaged and not), then finish as desired. Frankly, I think this is only going to generate opinions, but no vote to close yet.

Comment: How about a few pictures... they always help.

Comment: If that thing in the middle of your picture is one of the posts then 1) I have to question whether it's really "composite" (and not just wood), and 2) (regardless) just replace the post.  There's really nothing holding the post in place beyond a few nails/screws.

Comment: That sleeve might be a composite of iron and rust.

Comment: It may be difficult to tell, but there is a treated 4x4 post that is actually functioning as the post.  The piece that is deteriorating is a composite sleeve that slides over the 4x4 and matches the rest of the composite deck.  I have several that are in as bad shape as the one in the pic some have almost completely fallen apart, but I also have quite a few that look fine.